# Custom bundle in MVC 4 is not rendered

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I am working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. I want to make my own bundle containing `.js` files which I will use for validation but for some reason it's not working. Just to mention - if I render all my scripts in a given view everything is working fine like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
@Scriptes.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
//..few more files
```

but I don't want to include all those scripts each time so I decided to make my own bundle. The steps I made are:

- In `BundleConfig.cs` I have this :

> public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
>
> {
>
> //The defaults bundles
>
> bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customval").Include(

```
    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

> }

Then I check my `Global.asax` where I have this :

> BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

and then in my view I just try :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customval")
```

and `FireBug` is saying that no JavaScript is load for this page.

I use custom `_Layout` page and I wonder if I have to add something there. I added:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in my `_Layout` but it doesn't seem to solve something. So what am I missing to make my bundles working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably running in `DEBUG` mode. in this mode `.min.js` files are ignored (as they're only intended for Production use).

It would be best to include the non-minified (sometimes suffixes with `.debug.js`) versions, then on `RELEASE` mode the Optimization Framework will Bundle and Minify it for you automatically (unless you specify otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

I have had to add:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

at the end of the RegisterBundles method. In my old age :) I can't remember exactly what the issue was but it has to do with the .min files and debugging if memory serves me right.

The @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) is to allow you to have a special scripts section (optional in your case) defined in each view and have it rendered in the same place in every page that uses the _layout file.